# tinymce get image details on deletion

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce-4

I have created a plugin to handle image uploads for tinymce. THis is all working fine. What I want to be able to do is remove the image from my server if it is deleted by the  user so that I don't end up with gigs of orphanged files.

I have been able to listen for the nodechange envent using setup part of the tinymce init

```
<script src="//tinymce.cachefly.net/4.0/tinymce.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
tinymce.init({
    selector: "textarea",
    plugins: "autoresize",

    toolbar: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image jbimages",
    relative_urls: false,
        setup : function(ed) {
                    ed.on("NodeChange", function(e) {
        console.log('change event', e);
               });
}

});</script>
```

this gives me an event which I can see in the console, but I can't find a way of getting something from the event that tells me a img removal have been performed, so that i can delete the image from the server.

I have create a fiddle for this here [HERE](http://fiddle.tinymce.com/Efeaab)

if you load up your console and delete the image you will see what I mean. is there some property or method of the event that I am missing?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 7):

I was trying to do the same thing, but after much internet trawling & debugging the only way I could see to achieve this was to watch the editor for the delete or backspace keys being pushed while an image was selected in the editor.

So within your tinymce.init "setup" function:

```
ed.on('KeyDown', function (e) {

    if ((e.keyCode == 8 || e.keyCode == 46) && editor.selection) { // delete & backspace keys

        var selectedNode = editor.selection.getNode(); // get the selected node (element) in the editor

        if (selectedNode && selectedNode.nodeName == 'IMG') {

            MyCallback(selectedNode.src); // A callback that will let me invoke the deletion of the image on the server if appropriate for the image source.
        }
    }
});
```

I set this up within a new plugin, then added the callback as one of the settings of that plugin.

Comment: Interesting.. how does this work when you Ctrl+A with multiple elements.. say img's and p's and then delete?

Comment: Good point. In short, it doesn't. I tried Ctrl+A and the "selectedNode" in that case is the "body" tag of the TinyMCE IFrame. The method would have to be made more robust by iterating through child nodes of the selected node (if it's not an image) recursively and picking out all the images for processing. I'm pretty sure there will be other cases where you can delete a node that contains one or more images. As far as I can see you can't select more than one node (tried ctrl click, shift click & highlighting with the mouse)

Comment: Yeah. What i ended up doing was something very specific to my implementation. I hooked my images to the url (i have to maintain linkages in the database anyways). The server removes all the images except the ones in the html on submit.

Comment: using tinymce v4 instead of:
var selectedNode = editor.selection.getNode();
use:
var selectedNode = tinymce.activeEditor.selection.getNode();

Comment: This is a great solution, but one word of warning. If you want this to work on a mobile, when using the ‘mobile’ key configuration, then do not add this code as a plugin, because, currently, TinyMCE does not support custom plugins for mobile configurations. When I say mobile configuration, I mean ‘tinymce.init({mobile:{theme:’mobile’}});’...

Comment: And trust me, you need to use the mobile configuration, if  you plan to add support for mobile devices. The desktop configuration just doesn’t cut it, for mobile devices. Scrolling, amongst many other core features, just doesn’t work with the desktop configuration!

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion, I would like to do this job by using MutationObserver within init_instance_callback method.

```
init_instance_callback: function (editor) {
    //console.log("tinymce " + editor.id + " init finished.");

    var MutationObserver = window.MutationObserver || window.WebKitMutationObserver || window.MozMutationObserver;

    var observer = new MutationObserver(function (mutations, instance) {
        var addedImages = new Array();
        $.each(mutations, function (index, mutationRecord) {
            for (var i = 0; i < mutationRecord.addedNodes.length; i++) {
                var currentNode = mutationRecord.addedNodes[i];
                if (currentNode.nodeName == 'IMG' && currentNode.className != "mce-clonedresizable") {
                    if (addedImages.indexOf(currentNode.src) >= 0) continue;

                    addedImages.push(currentNode.getAttribute("src"));
                    continue;
                }

                var imgs = $(currentNode).find('img');
                for (var j = 0; j < imgs.length; j++) {
                    if (addedImages.indexOf(imgs[j].src) >= 0) continue;

                    addedImages.push(imgs[j].getAttribute("src"));
                }
            }
        });

        var removedImages = new Array();
        $.each(mutations, function (index, mutationRecord) {
            for (var i = 0; i < mutationRecord.removedNodes.length; i++) {
                var currentNode = mutationRecord.removedNodes[i];
                if (currentNode.nodeName == 'IMG' && currentNode.className != "mce-clonedresizable") {
                    if (removedImages.indexOf(currentNode.src) >= 0) continue;

                    removedImages.push(currentNode.getAttribute("src"));
                    continue;
                }

                var imgs = $(currentNode).find('img');
                for (var j = 0; j < imgs.length; j++) {
                    if (removedImages.indexOf(imgs[j].src) >= 0) continue;

                    removedImages.push(imgs[j].getAttribute("src"));
                }
            }
        });

        for (var i = 0; i < removedImages.length; i++) {
            var imageSrc = removedImages[i];
            if (addedImages.indexOf(imageSrc) >= 0) continue;

            if (confirm("delete image from server?\n" + imageSrc)) {
                //delete image from server.
            }
        };
    });
    
    observer.observe(editor.getBody(), {
        childList: true,
        subtree: true
    });
}
```

Comment: Works for me just fine. Thank You

Answer (score 2):

This variant was applied to tinyMCE-5, however it would be useful (I guess).

1. getting from server initial markup (value for editor);
2. parsing from the markup IDs of the images (regexp etc.);
3. saving in state array of the images IDs;
4. on adding new images to the editor we should add new IDs to the
   existing state (use images_upload_handler);
5. on submitting data we should parse editor's value again and compare
   it with existing state (in fact compare the two arrays);
6. call api.deleteImages on missing IDs.

Some details are not described here, but I think the general logic is clear. Such variant guarantees that we get (in 5) list of the final images after all paste/delete/cut, undo/redo etc. in editor. Also we avoid listeners and complex logic on every action in editor but handle all data only on get/submit.