# TinyMCE how to detect an image is removed

Tags: tinymce

I've been looking into the documentation of TinyMCE 4 [docs](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration) and I can't figure out how to detect an image in WYSIWIG is removed. 
When that occurs I want to remove it's parent, something simillar that is explained here: [API 3](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/API3:method.tinymce.dom.DOMUtils.remove). I am using version 4 by the way.

Answer (score 0):

I found something that I can work with, I might going to use DOMNodeRemoved event [tinymce get image details on deletion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23606559/tinymce-get-image-details-on-deletion)

Answer (score 0):

Mutation events like DOMNodeRemoved are deprecated. It is better to use Mutation Observes instead to detect removed nodes.

You may check for removed nodes and additaionally check if an img has been removed.